# Why my Ajax request isn't working with post method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I come to ask for help because I have a problem that persists for three days and I can't understand where the problem is. I have a form on an HTML page here :

```
<form id="contactformpage">
<div class="messages"></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="societepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Société</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="text" name="societe" class="form-control" id="societepage"  placeholder="Nom de la société" aria-describedby="indicsocietepage">
              <small id="indicsociete" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="adressepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" >Adresse</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="text" name="adresse" class="form-control" id="adressepage"  placeholder="Adresse">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="codepostaletvillepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" >Code postal & ville</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codepostaletville" id="codepostaletvillepage"  placeholder="Code postal & ville">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="contactpage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Nom du contact</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contactpage"  placeholder="Nom du contact">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="telephonepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Téléphone</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="téléphone" id="telephonepage" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" aria-describedby="indictelephonepage">
              <small id="indictelephonepage" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="mailpage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Adresse mail</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="mailpage" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse mail" aria-describedby="indicmailpage">
              <small id="indicmailpage" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="selecmarque" aria-describedby="indicmarquepage"> Marque du véhicule </label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <select class="form-control" name="marque" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;" onchange="generechoixmodele('selecmarque','apreschoixmarquepage','apreschoixmodelepage','nommodelepage','choixmodelepage','choixtypepage');" id="selecmarque">
                <option selected> Séléctionnez </option>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row"  id="apreschoixmarquepage" style="display:none;"> <!-- Liste déroulante qui apparait après le choix de la marque -->
              <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="apreschoixmarquepage" aria-describedby="indicmarque" id="nommodelepage"></label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <select class="form-control" name="modele" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;" id="choixmodelepage" onchange="generechoixtype('selecmarque','choixmodelepage','apreschoixmodelepage','nomtypepage','choixtypepage');">
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" id="apreschoixmodelepage" style="display:none;"> <!-- Liste déroulante qui apparait après le choix du modèle -->
              <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="apreschoixmodelepage" aria-describedby="indicmarque" id="nomtypepage"></label>
              <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
              <select class="form-control" name="type" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;" id="choixtypepage">
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
              <p> Je souhaite recevoir les catalogues suivants (dynamique)</p>
              <div id="choixcataloguepage">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="commentairepage">Commentaire</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="commentaire" id="commentairepage" rows="1"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="mail" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Captcha</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
                  <h6> Captcha à rajouter après </h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submitpage">
          </form>
```

And when I click on the button of this form, I send the data entered by the user thanks to an Ajax request on a php page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submitpage").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'sendform.php',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            societe : $("#societepage").val(),
            adresse : $("#adressepage").val(),
            codepostaletville : $("#codepostaletvillepage").val(),
            contact : $("#contactpage").val(),
            telephone : $("#telephonepage").val(),
            mail : $("#mailpage").val(),
            marqueclient : $("#selecmarque").val(),
            modeleclient : $("#choixmodelepage").val(),
            typeclient : $("#choixtypepage").val(),
            commentaire : $("#commentairepage").val()
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

            // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the
            var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
            var messageText = data.message;

            // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
            var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

            // If we have messageAlert and messageText
            if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                $('#contactformpage').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                // empty the form
                $('#contactformpage')[0].reset();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

});

I know it's possible to do $(this).serialize() for forms directly but I'd like to do that already. Here is the PHP script in question, so I send my data with the POST method, the problem is that this script tells me all the time "Form is empty" which means that the data was not sent with POST (since $ _POST is empty). And when I try to make an echo ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']), the php script returns an empty string, which means that the Ajax request was not made.

```
    <?php
/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
AND ALSO SMTP TO SEND THE EMAILS
*/
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/OAuth.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/POP3.php';
/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'lyes.tifoun@hotmail.fr';
$fromName = 'Demo contact form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'lyestfn@gmail.com';
$sendToName = 'Lyes Tifoun';
// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// smtp credentials and server

$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$smtpUsername = 'nom_utilisateur';
$smtpPassword = 'mdp';

$fields = array('societe' => 'Société', 'adresse' => 'Adresse', 'codepostaletville' => 'Code postal et ville', 'contact' => 'Nom du contact', 'téléphone' => 'Numéro de téléphone', 'mail' => 'Adresse mail', 'marque' => 'Marque du véhicule', 'modele' => 'Modèle du véhicule', 'type' => 'Type du véhicule', 'commentaire' => 'Commentaire');

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';


$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
try {
    if (count($_POST) == 0) {
        throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
    }

    $emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a nice day,<br>Best,<br>Ondrej</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname($smtpHost);
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));
    $mail->Username = $smtpUsername;
    $mail->Password = $smtpPassword;
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
    $mail->addReplyTo($from);




    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = 'test';//$emailTextHtml;
    $mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version of the HTML email, very handy


    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';


    if (!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

I would like to understand why my request doesn't work because I don't think I made any syntax or other errors.
Here is the script used for the JQuery library in my HTML file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

And I use WAMPServer to run my site locally, I already did my research but could the problem come from there by chance? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Open the network tab in your browsers dev-tools, submit the form and see what data actually gets sent to PHP. Even if the selectors are wrong in JS, it should still post the fields (but with empty values).

Comment: Also as a side note; given your form you **cannot** use `serialize()`.  None of your form inputs have `name` attributes, which serialize requires to know what to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it will?  https://jsfiddle.net/gqbj83s7/  It doesn't appear that javascript will interchange `undefined` for empty string.  That would be weird if it did, actually.  An empty string is an actual value.

Comment: Yes my fault I've sent the wrong form actually the ids match. There's no data sent to PHP.

Comment: @Taplar - True. I was thinking a bit backwards :-).

Answer (score 0):

I come back to you to inform you that my data is finally sent with $_POST as shown by the network panel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnh5F.png)

I've also made a var_dump($_SERVER) and the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] value is "XML HTTPREQUEST" which indicates that the Ajax request has been launched. Now I have an other problem : I don't have a client-side response: currently the program seems to validate the condition `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')` and I have an `echo($encoded)` in JSON format as shown below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYqlB.png)

Therefore I should have a client-side response, which is not the case actually.

Thanks a lot for your responses and sorry for my bad english.